# How can I reveal type hints in PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting, mypy

Python's `mypy` has a special function called [`reveal_type()`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#displaying-the-type-of-an-expression) which asks the linter to display the type of variables.

PyCharm does not support it and instead shows the function as non-existing.

How can I display the type hint of a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, PyCharm binds the **`F1`** key to the "display documentation" command.

[image: PyCharm example screenshot]

When displaying the documentation, you're able to see the type of variables, function signatures, class signatures, and docstrings.

You're also able to view the type directly using **`ctrl+shift+P`** or by hovering with the mouse and pressing **`ctrl`**.

If you do not use the default keymap, you may navigate to View | Quick documentation:

[image]

Comment: In PyCharm 2020.3, Ctrl+Hover is now only showing `variable "b"`

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+P still works in 2022! Very handy!